# Pandas and scikit-learn: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to fit Knearest Neigbors model to my data. but, I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Here is the code to my Knearest Neigbhors algorithm:

```
def knn_train_test_new(training_col, target_col, df):
    np.random.seed(1)
    df = df.loc[np.random.permutation(len(df))]
#    shuffled_index = np.random.permutation(df.index)
#   df = df.reindex(shuffled_index)

    train_df = df.iloc[0:150] #training set has 75% of the data
    test_df = df.iloc[150:] #test set has 25% of the data  
    k = [5]

    rmse = {}

    for k_val in k:

        model = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = k_val)
        model.fit(train_df[training_col], train_df[target_col])

        predictions = model.predict(test_df[training_col])

        mse = mean_squared_error(test_df[target_col], predictions)

        rmse[k_val] = (mse ** 0.5)

    return rmse

two_features = ["width", "wheel-base"]
rmse_val = knn_train_test(two_features, 'price', numeric_cars)
```

And the top five rows of my dataframe:

```
numeric_cars.head()
```

[image]

I don't get this error when I use shuffled_index( which I have commented) instead of np.random.permutation. I don't clearly understand the difference between the two.

The complete error track:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-03e0dd7acfd0> in <module>()
     25 
     26 two_features = ["width", "wheel-base"]
---> 27 rmse_val = knn_train_test_new(two_features, 'price', numeric_cars)
     28 
     29 #rmse_results = {}

<ipython-input-13-03e0dd7acfd0> in knn_train_test_new(training_col, target_col, df)
     14 
     15         model = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = k_val)
---> 16         model.fit(train_df[training_col], train_df[target_col])
     17 
     18         predictions = model.predict(test_df[training_col])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py in fit(self, X, y)
    743         """
    744         if not isinstance(X, (KDTree, BallTree)):
--> 745             X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
    746         self._y = y
    747         return self._fit(X)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    571     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite,
    572                     ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
--> 573                     ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    574     if multi_output:
    575         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    451                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
    452         if force_all_finite:
--> 453             _assert_all_finite(array)
    454 
    455     shape_repr = _shape_repr(array.shape)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X)
     42             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     43         raise ValueError("Input contains NaN, infinity"
---> 44                          " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
     45 
     46 

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Comment: Post the full error traceback.

Comment: @Denziloe I edited the question

Comment: Look at the second arrow. The traceback shows that the code you ran to get the error is not the same as the code you posted here. Change it to the code you posted here and you won't have this error. It should be clear to you why the code was wrong.

Comment: It was an error in jupyter notebook but I edited my question with a new issue.

Comment: the error is relatively explanatory - you have a bad data point. You probably don't get it when you shuffle the index because you're not selecting that row. Find the data point that is not like the rest (null, infinity, etc)

Comment: "It was an error in jupyter notebook" -- no, it was an error in the code that you typed into jupyter notebook.

Comment: @flyingmeatball My dataframe doesn't have null values. Still, I am getting this error. Let me inspect the data points further.

Comment: @Denziloe - Whoops! Ya, It was error in my code.

Comment: @MJP Simply store the values that are causing the error in a variable. Then examine them. sklearn isn't lying, if it says you're giving it bad values you've given it bad values.